# Let $ A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} $ be a positive semidefinite matrix, and let $x, y \in \mathbb R^n $. If $\langle x, y \rangle \geq 0 $ then ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Can we prove the following statement?

Let $ A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} $ be a positive semidefinite matrix, and let $x, y \in \mathbb R^n $. If $\langle x, y \rangle \geq 0 $ then $\langle x, Ay \rangle \geq 0 $.

Comment: The question title seems unrelated to the question body. Also, the statement in the question body is certainly false: consider $A=-I$ and $x=y\ne0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider
$$
x = \pmatrix{4\\1}, \quad y = \pmatrix{1\\4}, \quad A = \pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}.
$$
We have $\langle x,y \rangle = 8 > 0$ but $\langle x,Ay \rangle = -1 < 0$.